# get better info on Dojo errors

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, dojo

Somethimes Dojo doesn't offers a lot of info on some errors. Is there a way to get more info on a certain error ? 
Example below: 
How can I know what is actually wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you want to ask, please specify your error.

Comment: Check the network tab to see if you are receiving any server errors (400/500s etc.)